# In PHP, using DomDocument getElementByID not working? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementbyid, nodevalue

Here is a bit of my code...

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$html = $newIDs[0];
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$tryID = $dom->getElementById('ID');
echo $tryID;
```

I am trying to get multiple specific IDs from a website, this just shows one, and I have seen this method everywhere, including on here, but when I try and print something out nothing shows up. I tried testing to see if it is reading something in with

```
if(!$tryID)
{
    ("Element not found");
}
```

But it never prints that out either. Lastly, I have used

```
echo $tryID->nodeValue;
```

and still nothing... anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Also, if I do get this working can I read in multiple different things to different variables on the same $dom ? If that makes ay sense.

Comment: Keep in mind, when you're dealing with Objects or Arrays, `print_r($element)` will give you READABLE info on the Object/Array. It's one of the best debugging tools you get on PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so your solution.

For a DIV:

```
<div id="divID" name="notWorking">This is not working!</div>
```

This will do:

```
<?php

    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('YourFile.html');
    $div = $dom->getElementById('divID');

    echo $div->textContent;

    $div->setAttribute("name", "yesItWorks");
?>
```

Should work without the file as long as you pass a Well-Made XML or XHTML content, changing

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile('YourFile.html');
```

to your

```
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Oh yeah, and of course, to CHANGE the content (For completeness):

```
$div->removeChild($div->firstChild);
$newText = new DOMText('Yes this works!');
$div->appendChild($newText);
```

Then you can just Echo it again or something.

Comment: Life saver. I changed it up a little to fit my exact situation, but this helped out so much. Also, I might add for anyone else that uses this... if the HTML file is not "properly formatted" it will run, but give a bunch of warnings. You can suppress markup errors by switching... $dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html'); ... to ... @$dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html');